# Missing participant is_test field in drupal views

Tags: civievent, drupal-views

We would like to use the participant is_test field in drupal views but cannot seem to do so. 
1. Would anyone be able to tell us how we can do so?
or
2. Can anyone show us with an example that will help us create a pr to add this field.

Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Jaap, I now added it by this PR: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/issues/95 From CiviCRM 5.21 i guess this will be included.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the field to this file: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/7.x-master/modules/views/components/civicrm.event.inc